# Python program giving error us/bin/env python no such file with crontab

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

I'm try to get a job in crontab to run twice per day at different times. It is a python script that calls other python scripts and a bash script as functions. All of the scripts are located in the path given in the crontab. The crontab looks like this:

```
PATH=/home/test/Desktop/UntitledFolder/ContinuousTest
0 08 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /home/test/Desktop/UntitledFolder/ContinuousTest/automated.py
46 10 * * * /home/test/Desktop/UntitledFolder/ContinuousTest/automated.py
```

The code looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses
import os


def Move():
    os.system("cd /home/test/Desktop/UntitledFolder/ContinuousTest")


def Upgrade():
    os.system("python upgrade.py")
    os.system("python upgrade.py")


def Setup():
    os.system("python setup.py")
    os.system("python setup2.py")

def Throughput():
    os.system("./test.sh")

def Sleep():
    os.system("sleep 320")

Move()  
Setup()
Upgrade()
Sleep()
Throughput()
```

I see that when the script is run from the cronjob, I get this error:
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory

What could be the problem?

Comment: `cronjob` runs as different user, with different privileges and with different environment (ie. it can has different paths in variable `PATH`). You may have to use full path to python - ie `/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/env` must search `PATH` to find the `python` executable to run. Since you completely replace `PATH` with only a single directory, and don't include the usual `/bin`, and `/usr/bin` paths, `env` cannot find `python` to run.

The solution is to either set `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/home/test/Desktop/UntitledFolder/ContinuousTest`, or just dispense with `env` altogether and put `#!/usr/bin/python` (or `python3` if that is the intention) at the top of your script.

Another reasonable solution would be to not set `PATH` in your `crontab`, but put `PATH` modifications inside the script as necessary instead - that might lead to fewer surprises down the road if you add additional jobs to your `crontab`.